# Searching in a listview using a Custom Adapter with text and images

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-adapter, android-filterable

I am configuring a resource in my app to search in a Listview using a custom Adapter. I using an EditText to type the string and passing the text to Adapter on addTextChangedListener Event, but it is not working.

I configure the adapter with "implements Filterable" and enable Listview with ".setTextFilterEnabled(true)", but doesn´t work.

I saw that I must  implement "public Filter getFilter()" but I have no idea how can I do that.

When I type some words in EditText, like "cel" or "12" the filter goes in action, but the result is always the same: The first two items in Listview, no matter what is into the Listview (the content of listview is random).

Below a snippet of my Fragment Activity:

```
public class VideosFragment extends Fragment {

private ListView listView;
private ArrayList<String> idVideo = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<String> titleVideo = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<String> descVideo = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<String> urlVideo = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<String> channelTitle = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<String> canalTitle = new ArrayList<>();
private ArrayList<String> canalId = new ArrayList<>();
private CustomFiltraCanaisAdapter customFiltraCanaisAdapter;
private EditText editText;

CustomVideoAdapter customVideoAdapter;

public VideosFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_videos, container, false);


    // Configure Listview
    listView = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.listView_videos);

    //Create search parameters
    editText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.searchList);
    listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
    editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            String text = editText.getText().toString().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
            VideosFragment.this.customVideoAdapter.getFilter().filter(text);
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

        }
    });
```

and below my CustomAdapter:

```
public class CustomVideoAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> implements Filterable {

private final Activity context;
private final ArrayList<String> videoTitle;
private final ArrayList<String> videoDesc;
private final ArrayList<String> videoId;
private final ArrayList<String> channelTitle;
private final ArrayList<String> imgurl;

public CustomVideoAdapter(Activity context, ArrayList<String> videoTitle,
                                            ArrayList<String> videoId,
                                            ArrayList<String> channelTitle,
                                            ArrayList<String> imgurl,
                                            ArrayList<String> videoDesc) {
    super(context, R.layout.custom_lista_videos, videoTitle);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

    this.context = context;
    this.videoTitle = videoTitle;
    this.videoDesc = videoDesc;
    this.videoId = videoId;
    this.channelTitle = channelTitle;
    this.imgurl = imgurl;
}
public View getView(int position,View view,ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater=context.getLayoutInflater();
    View rowView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_lista_videos, null,true);

    TextView txtTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txtVideoTitle);
    ImageView imgPhoto = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.imgPhoto);
    TextView txtChannelTitle = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txtChannelTitle);
    TextView txtVideoId = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txtVideoId);
    TextView txtVideoDesc = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.txtVideoDesc);

    txtTitle.setText(videoTitle.get(position));
    Picasso.with(context).load(imgurl.get(position)).into(imgPhoto);
    txtChannelTitle.setText(channelTitle.get(position));
    txtVideoId.setText(videoId.get(position));
    txtVideoDesc.setText(videoDesc.get(position));
    return rowView;

};
```

What is missing?

After some helps I trying to create (and use) a Model Class, but I still have no progress because I did not figure out how can I must change my code on "CustomAdapter" to use correctly this code.

My Model Class is below:

public class FilteredVideoAdapter {

```
private ArrayList<String> storedVideoTitle = null;
private ArrayList<String> storedVideoDesc = null;
private ArrayList<String> storedVideoId = null;
private ArrayList<String> storedChannelTitle = null;
private ArrayList<String> storedImgurl = null;

public FilteredVideoAdapter(){

}

public ArrayList<String> getStoredVideoTitle() {
    return storedVideoTitle;
}

public void setStoredVideoTitle(ArrayList<String> storedVideoTitle) {
    this.storedVideoTitle = storedVideoTitle;
}

public ArrayList<String> getStoredVideoDesc() {
    return storedVideoDesc;
}

public void setStoredVideoDesc(ArrayList<String> storedVideoDesc) {
    this.storedVideoDesc = storedVideoDesc;
}

public ArrayList<String> getStoredVideoId() {
    return storedVideoId;
}

public void setStoredVideoId(ArrayList<String> storedVideoId) {
    this.storedVideoId = storedVideoId;
}

public ArrayList<String> getStoredChannelTitle() {
    return storedChannelTitle;
}

public void setStoredChannelTitle(ArrayList<String> storedChannelTitle) {
    this.storedChannelTitle = storedChannelTitle;
}

public ArrayList<String> getStoredImgurl() {
    return storedImgurl;
}

public void setStoredImgurl(ArrayList<String> storedImgurl) {
    this.storedImgurl = storedImgurl;
}

public FilteredVideoAdapter withFilteredVideoAdapter(
        ArrayList<String> storedVideoTitle,
        ArrayList<String> storedVideoDesc,
        ArrayList<String> storedVideoId,
        ArrayList<String> storedChannelTitle,
        ArrayList<String> storedImgurl){

    this.storedVideoTitle = storedVideoTitle;
    this.storedVideoDesc = storedVideoDesc;
    this.storedVideoId = storedVideoId;
    this.storedChannelTitle = storedChannelTitle;
    this.storedImgurl = storedImgurl;

    return this;
}
```

}

Comment: what exactly you want to search in your listView? Is it video title

Comment: @RahulChandrabhan, yes! But I need filter on VideoTitle but the others informations about the filtered video must be tied with it. The solution posted by lib4 works on VideoTitle, but the informations on Listview are missed, like VideoID, VideoDesc and the others.

Comment: You have to create a pojo for your video information so that all data are bound by each other and it is easy to work with that, dont create separate arraylist for every information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what you have to do inside your adapter, you might need to do some tweaks:-

```
 @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return new Filter() {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                FilterResults results = new FilterResults();



                // If the constraint (search string/pattern) is null
                // or its length is 0, i.e., its empty then
                // we just set the `values` property to the
                // original contacts list which contains all of them
                if (constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0) {
                    results.values =   videoTitle;;
                    results.count = videoTitle.size();
                }
                else {
                    // Some search copnstraint has been passed
                    // so let's filter accordingly
                    ArrayList<String> filteredTitle = new ArrayList<String>();

                    // We'll go through all the title and see
                    // if they contain the supplied string
                    for (String c : string) {
                        if (string.toUpperCase().contains( constraint.toString().toUpperCase() )) {
                            // if `contains` == true then add it
                            // to our filtered list
                            filteredTitle.add(c);
                        }
                    }

                    // Finally set the filtered values and size/count
                    results.values = filteredTitle;
                    results.count = filteredTitle.size();
                }

                // Return our FilterResults object
                return results;
            }
            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
                mList = (ArrayList<String>) results.values;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        };
    }
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18429765)

Comment: @zapping  Edited my answer, Added example how to do.  Upvote welcomed.

Comment: @lib4, I made some adjusts:: " for (String c : videoTitle) { if (c.toLowerCase().contains( constraint.toString().toLowerCase() ))" and add "ArrayList<String> mList" to publishResults method and filter now is working. I can see this when I set Log.i , but the adapter is not updated, so, the filter is working fine, but not applying in adapter the results.

Comment: What r u doing in publishResults() could u pls post the code. Publish result we have to notify the dataset. make sure mList in my answer should your adapter list. Need to make sure your listview is reading from the newely  updated mList. @Andre

Comment: @lib4, follow my publishResults()
`
            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
                ArrayList<String> mList = (ArrayList<String>) results.values;
                for (String list: mList){
                    videoTitle.add(list);
                    //Log.i("filtro", "Results: " +list);
                }
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        };
`

Comment: did u cleared VideoTitle.clear() before adding the new list? Possible u post the updated Adapter class.

Comment: @lib4, now the filter is working and updating the listview, but, in my case, I have other fields that must be updated together on listview, like "Video Channel, "Video ID", "Video Desc" and "Image of Video", so, when the filter goes on, only videoTitle array is being filtered. I tried to get videoTitle position and pass to the others arrays, but doesn´t work. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: @Andre If the solution working for you please accept the answer and upvote,  should benefit others too. I will check the case u mentioned. Thanks

Comment: @lib4 , when the filter is applyed, the other informations on Listview are missed, like VideoId, VideoDesc, channelTitle and imgurl. All these informations must be tied whith the video filtered by VideoTitle. I tried from several ways since yesterday, but the informations still mixed.

Comment: This is because you have around 7 arrays if information. And you want to map these information somehow based on index. The best approach to solve this problem is create a Model class. Example: Class VideoInfo{tile,description, .....}

Comment: @lib4, I created the model class but I having difficulty to used it on my CustomAdapter. I edited my question an posted my model class. Could you please help me with that?

Comment: @Andre The Modal class seems to be wrongly implemented. The main motive of implementing modal class in your case is to avoid using all these  ArrayList. But you wrapped inside modal class which adds more overhead.

Comment: btw how to  populate ArrayList,I mean  storedVideoTitle , videoDesc ... do u have code for that?  How do you map videoTitle with video description?

Comment: @lib4 I using retrofit inside a fragment. So I create ArrayList on that fragment an fill with all informations about each video, like:
` titleVideo.add(response.body().getItems().get(i).getSnippet().getTitle());
idVideo.add(response.body().getItems().get(i)...
descVideo.add(response.body().getItems().get(i)...
urlVideo.add(response.body().getItems().get(i)...
channelTitle.add(response.body().getItems().get(i)... ` 
After that I create an instance of CustomAdapter and put these informations: CustomVideoAdapter(getActivity(), titleVideo, idVideo, channelTitle, urlVideo, descVideo);

Comment: You should do something like this. 
 Item[] items = response.body().getItems();
ArrayList< VideoModel> videos = new ArrayList< VideoModel 
>(); 
for(int i =0 ;i < items.size(); i++) {
 VideoModel video = new VideoModel();

video.title =  items[i].getSnippet(‌​).getTitle();
video.description = items[i].getSnippet(‌​).getdescription());
.
.
.
videos.add(video);
}

Now you will have only one ArrayList<videos>

Comment: After a long time I finally got what I looking for! I really thank you @lib4 by the help! I made several adjusts on my app and now everything is working fine! Thanks again!

Comment: That's great,  Happy Coding

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without using filterable, Try this code

### Your Activity Code

```
vendorSearchEt.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            if (vendorSearchEt.getText().toString().length() == 0) {
                if (vendorsListAdapter != null) {
                    vendorsListAdapter.filter("");
                }
            } else {
                String text = vendorSearchEt.getText().toString().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
                if (vendorsListAdapter != null) {
                    vendorsListAdapter.filter(text);
                }
            }

        }
    });
```

### Adapter Class

```
public class VendorsListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

// Declare Variables \\
Context mContext;
LayoutInflater inflater;
private List<VendorsList> vendorsLists = null;
private ArrayList<VendorsList> arrayListVendorsList = null;
AppCompatActivity act;

public VendorsListAdapter(Context context,
                          List<VendorsList> vendorsLists) {
    mContext = context;
    this.vendorsLists = vendorsLists;
    arrayListVendorsList = new ArrayList<>(vendorsLists);
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
    act = (AppCompatActivity) context;

}

public class ViewHolder {

    TextView vendorNameTv;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return vendorsLists.size();
}

@Override
public VendorsList getItem(int position) {
    return vendorsLists.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(final int position, View view, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder holder;
    if (view == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.lv_items_vendors_list, null);

        holder.vendorNameTv = view.findViewById(R.id.lv_items_vendors_name_tv);
        holder.vendorNameTv.setTypeface(StaticMethods.customFont(act, "Quicksand-Regular.otf"));

        view.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    }

    holder.vendorNameTv.setText(vendorsLists.get(position).getVendorName());

    return view;
}

/**
 * Filter Class for item searching
 *
 * @param charText Text to be searched
 */
public void filter(String charText) {
    charText = charText.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
    vendorsLists.clear();

    if (charText.length() == 0) {
        vendorsLists.addAll(arrayListVendorsList);
    } else {
        for (VendorsList vendorsList : arrayListVendorsList) {
            if (vendorsList.getVendorName().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault())
                    .contains(charText)) {
                vendorsLists.add(vendorsList);
            }
        }
    }
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}}
```